# Controller and ng-model directive in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is the following code:

```
function MyController($scope) {
 $scope.name = 'John';
 $scope.show = true;
}
<div ng:app>
 <form name="form" ng-controller="MyController">
   <div data-ng-switch="show">
     <input data-ng-switch-when="true" type="text" data-ng-model="name" />
   </div>
   Name: {{name}} 
 </form>
</div>
```

It code works strangely: when my views has been loaded I see input with 'John' value, it's good. But when I'm trying to input some new value in field my {{name}} output doesn't change. Why??

Comment: I think you should revise your syntax  , for example ng:app ? look weird

Comment: seems `ng-switch` create own scope, so when you change in input - you change value in nested scope. You can try change it to `$scope.user={name:"John"}`, and `data-ng-model="user.name" ` and `Name: {{user.name}} `

Comment: Grundy - yes it works, but I don't understand why. Can you create a detailed answer?

Comment: @malcoauri google "angular dot rule" for explanations. it's just normal javascript behavior of prototypical inheritance.

Comment: dfsq can you provide me explanation in my context?

Comment: @HEPİMİZYARBAYMEHMETALKANIZ It's valid syntax, as well as `data-ng-app` or `x-ng-app`.

Comment: Grundy has already explained it well. ngSwitch creates new scope which prototypical inherits from the outer, and since you are using primitive value for model, you get the behavior you see.

Comment: try see this doc:https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller#scope-inheritance-example